# Can you have 1 HTTP cookie updated from any path of a site?

Tags: http, cookies

My user can enter the server domain site with various paths to pages and data; Is there a way all paths can read and write the same HTTP cookie?
The Path=/ option seems to only apply to reading - selecting for sending in subsequent requests, but every path response results in writing a different cookie for its path. Paths can return multiples of the same cookie.
Is there an alternative for server to store info in response headers and have it returned in subsequent requests regardless of the request path?

Update & Answer: Cookies with path=/ option added work well and can be repeatedly updated and retrieved by any path; Beware that old cookies without a path option might suddenly reappear in browser tools only when those paths are accessed during a session.

Comment: Path=/ should work. This is pretty standard behavior. Consider for example a `/login` endpoint setting a cookie for the entire domain. If you're not seeing that behavior, maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: /a/x.html can set a cookie with path=/ and if /b/y.html wants to change it it can’t even with path=/. There are 2 cookies.

Comment: I was fairly sure you're wrong about this, but I wasn't a 100% sure. I wrote a quick server that does this, and it does indeed work perfectly. My guess is that you have a different kind of problem. A lot of folks are running into issues when clients don't do 1 but multiple (parallel) requests, for example when fetching other resources like images. The last `Set-Cookie` with the same Path wins, so take a look at your network tab and go over *every* request/response, not just the main ones.

Comment: You are right; My faith in cookies is restored.  path=/ works.
I was confused by old cookie experiments suddenly reappearing in the browser tools when old URL paths were accessed again. My bad.